# Magento 2 - extension attributes

Tags: magento2

Do I always have to add new column in DB (by creating `InstallSchema` file) when I'm defining Extention Attribute (scalar) for an entity, or it's being done automatically somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save **Extension Attributes** to DB than you need to add column.

Regarding DB : It stores to the relative table of entity.

**For Example:**

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface">
    <attribute code="start_date" type="string" />
    <attribute code="end_date" type="string" />
    <attribute code="brands" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Above my code is for **Sales Rule** Extension Attributes, So it will store to **RuleInterface** realted table that is `salesrule`.

Hope Now its clear from you.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit clearer now, yes.  Do I have to set the column separately (in Install/Upgrade Schema)?

Comment: Sure. If it clear your understanding, Mark up vote and accept answer to help others :) Happy Coding !!

Comment: @PeteJaworski, Yes, You have to if you want to save it in DB.

Comment: so if I want extension attribute for CartItemInterface then I might want to add column in quoteitem table, correct?

Comment: @PeteJaworski, Yups, That Right.

Comment: Exactly the answer i have been looking for, Magento's doc should have clarified this better instead of being too vague, upvoted both the answer and the question, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

NO,you should **define your attribute as an extension attribute** by define your attribute in `extension_attribute.xml` at your module.

`InstallSchema/UpgradeSchema` does **not able** to define **an attribute as extension attribute**.

Comment: I know it should be defined in extension_attribute.xml, but where exactly is it stored in the DB?

Comment: Yes, i have a attribute database like other attributes which are created  from admin. Use of  extension attribute  is that to ability to update custom attribute via api . Actually,  Now magento trying to use API class for `frontend/admin`.